# custom fields style in office word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I have a word file that I use Zotero for refrencing.
Zotero Use field in the word to insert my references.
all my paragraph use normal style.
when i insert the refrence in the end of any paragraph I want to automatically that words created by reference field to use another style
is there any way that i can create custom style for inserted field in the word?
thank you

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65nHl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way that i can create custom style for inserted field in
> the word?

You can certainly create a custom style. It will not very likely apply automatically but it is really simple to apply a style.

For Word 365 (and likely earlier) use the Style Icon on the Home ribbon and use an existing style or create your own custom style (give it a name for easy reference).

"Styles" is the Word way (almost forever) for formatting a specific block of text with a specific style.

Here is a screen shot with the fundamentals to guide you.

If you need to apply the custom style many times, you would need to build a Word Macro (View Ribbon) that can identify the text and apply the style.

[image: Word 365 Styles]

Comment: thank you for your answer. this way is easy for small documents. I use about 300 references and i want to automatically word use my selected style for that field in insertion time. in easy word i want to set a style for my field and word automatically change format based on the selected style

Comment: You would need to build a Word Macro (that would be custom for your situation) .  I noted that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

another answer from zotero froum:
Not at citation insert time, but you can use Word's Find and Replace feature to search for ^d which will find all Fields, then you can apply whatever formatting you want with the Replace feature as a batch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).